# Undefined method has_attached_file after Paperclip installation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, imagemagick, paperclip

Not sure if I've done everything right here.  I added the Paperclip gem to my Gemfile and did bundle install. I followed along with the readme instructions on Paperclips Github page.

I wasn't sure if I needed to install ImageMagick. But, I found a script on Github for installation on Snow Leopard, so I ran:

rails plugin install http://github.com/masterkain/ImageMagick-sl.git

But, now I'm getting Undefined method has_attached_file

I'm completely new to Rails and programming.  Most of this is pretty advanced for me, but so far I've managed to figure stuff out.

Comment: Post your model please and did you added 'require "paperclip"'?

Answer (score 3):

Have you restarted your rails server?

Comment: Geez. Thank you. Restarting the server solved the problem with has_attached_file. Now I'm getting No route matches {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"products"}

Comment: Here's my model:<br />class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :colors
  has_attached_file :avatar,
    :styles => {
      :medium => "300x300>",
      :thumb => "100x100>"
    },
    :path => ":class/:attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
    :default_url => "/images/missing/:class/:attachment/:style.jpg"
end<br />This is how I structured the form:<br /><%= form_for @product, :url => product_path, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>

Comment: Have you setup your routes file with the products resources? Do you have a destroy method in your products controller?